# Doctrine 2.8 forces eager loading

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony 5.4 with Doctrine 2.8 and I am trying to load an array of entities via query builder, but I don't need any of this entity's relations. Unfortunately, all the relations load no matter what I do, resulting in lots of unnecessary queries. Even when I set the all of its relation annotations to lazy load, it loads them all anyway.

My query is very simple as I only need an array of User entities to fill out a Symfony form with their ids and names:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.last_name', 'ASC')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I've also tried it this way as well:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name from App\Entity\User u')->getResult();
```

I have tried setting each relation's annotation in the entity class like so:

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="user", fetch="LAZY")
```

or even:

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="user", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
```

And I still get numerous queries trying to pull all its relations.

The only solution that works thus far is to comment out all the relations in the entity class, which of course is not a solution at all. Is there a way to force Doctrine to stop eager loading all the User relations?

Comment: What indicates that all relations are being loaded?

Comment: It's possible that you have one to one relations, and the behaviour  always is load the associates.

Comment: Anything that happens to access the getter will trigger a fetch including perhaps a dump($entity) statement.  Or maybe a form type.  Try querying an entity then do absolutely nothing with it and look at the profile query data.

Comment: It's One-To-One Bidirectional relation problem. You should use One-To-One Unidirectional relation or add @ORM\JoinColumn for address property in the user entity. For more information, see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/faq.html#why-is-an-extra-sql-query-executed-every-time-i-fetch-an-entity-with-a-one-to-one-relation

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I didn't realize that with Doctrine you have no choice but to eager load all 1:1 relations. I may just have to do a bunch of JOINS to avoid this n+1 issue.

Comment: ...or create a DTO for this entity.

Comment: @JoelJoelBinks Not sure how you reached your conclusion eager loading but it's wrong.  I made a simple test case just to satisfy myself on that.  I can give you a link if your want.  Understand that quite a bit happens with any current user as part of the request/response cycle.  So something unexpected may be loading in the address but it's not specifically a Doctrine thing.

Comment: Sure, send it over.

Comment: @Cerad to answer your question, it was mentioned above but I also asked someone in the Symfony Slack channel and he said that 1:1 relations are always eager loaded.

Comment: As @Artem pointed out, it is the difference between [unidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) and [bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) relations.  A uni relation will lazy load as you originally expected.  A bi relation will (depending on which side has the inversedBy attribute) eager load using a join.  I'm still not sure why it needs to but it is what it is.

Comment: That sounds correct. The Symfony Slack channel told me this: "To avoid the extra loads you have to either: fetch join through a custom DQL query e.g.: select(a, b, c)->join(a.b)->join(a.c) but if you have a lot this is really inefficient (and I question your data model), or you have to change the direction of the relationship to avoid having an inverse 1:1 relationship. I find this one kinda hard to wrap my head around, but if I get it right it means having the foreign key in the dependent entity so e.g. a User with a Profile 1:1 you need to have the foreign key in the profile...

Comment: "...(so user_profiles.user_id) not the user (users.profile_id), otherwise loading a User would always pull the profile … provided I got that the right way around!
finally you can instead use a 1:many relationship and programmatically treat it as a 1:1 by hiding the fact it is a collection and only ever allowing a single element in it. I have used this one as I found it cognitively easier to deal with and the code is trivial while allowing for easy future expansion should you need multiple records in the future."

Comment: I decided to bypass Doctrine altogether and use raw SQL to solve this problem.

Comment: @JoelJoelBinks Got a chuckle over the raw SQL comment.  I do that all the time especially for read only stuff.  SQL databases like to be normalized which means Doctrine entity trees end up being normalized which is often inconvenient at the domain level.  Simply fetching exactly what your need is often worth the extra developer time spent in writing the query and mapping the results.

Comment: Going back to relations, not sure if you tried it but you can actually setup two uni-directional 1:1 relations.  One in each direction.  Just drop the inversedBy and mappedBy attributes.  That gives you lazy loading as well as the ability to still use joins when querying if needed.